# Remove container when all children is dismissed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

I am trying to remove the parent container when the children li are removed. Each li has a dismissal anchor that once it is clicked, the li is removed.

What I would like is for that when all the li are removed, the div container will also be removed.

I am currently using backbone.js

```
<div class="container>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="dismiss"></a></li>
    <li><a class="dismiss"></a></li>
    <li><a class="dismiss"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `if(!$(".container ul li").length){ $(".container").remove();}`

Comment: What is your javascript until now?

Comment: @Sebsemillia I've only written the js for the dismissal. as simple as using .remove()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click",".dismiss",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parent("li").remove();

   if(!$(".container ul li").length){ 
      $(".container").remove();
   }
});
```

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5CpH8/1)**